# setActionButton accepts just first pendingIntent

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

When building CustomTabsIntent using builder and setting setActionButton:

```
new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(getSession())
            .setActionButton(getShareIcon(),
                             "Share text",
                             getShareIntent(),
                             true)
            .build()
```

Crude implementation of getShareIntent:

```
@NonNull
private PendingIntent getShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(mContext, ShareBroadcastReceiver.class);
    shareIntent.putExtra("extra", someValue);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, shareIntent, 0);
}
```

I espect to get the extra's content in my Broadcast receiver. It works but when I rebuild it with different "someValue" I receive the initaial someValue.

Custom Tabs seem to only send the initial intent and ignore the updated intents until the Custom Tab Service is restarted.

The behaviour is not documented. Is it a bug?

Comment: Thank you @Selvin PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as the last parameter did work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem

```
@NonNull
private PendingIntent getShareIntent() {
   Intent shareIntent = new Intent(mContext, ShareBroadcastReceiver.class);
   shareIntent.putExtra("extra", someValue);
   return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, shareIntent, 0);
}
```

2nd Parameter is the requestCode which should be different for different broadcast

Replace

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, shareIntent, 0);
```

with

```
PendingIntent.getBroadCast(mContext, requestCode , shareIntent, 0}
```

Generate a different requestCode each time

Comment: Another option would be using the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, to change the value of the extra. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT